# Why total internal reflection happens while in this process light come back to the (optically) denser medium instead of leaving it?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light

If denser medium tend to decrease the speed of light (that is why the light rays get refracted to travel a shorter distance to maintain the highest speed possible) Then why total internal reflection happen? if light escapes the denser medium then it will be at more speed - right? then why do the opposite of what is intended?

Answer (score 0):

The actual motion is due to wave behaviour, and the wave will only exit the optically dense medium if Snell's Law can be satisfied. In the case of Total Internal Reflection, no physically possible angle allows Snell's Law to be satisfied, and so the wave can only reflect back into the optically dense medium. It is not all about maintaining the highest speed possible. The rest of the situation must allow the trajectory you want to try.

Comment: Snell's Law deals with angle of incident.  I do not have any  doubt in that.  I asked the question on the Fermat's "principal of least time." How total internal reflection justify principal of least time?

Comment: You can derive Snell's Law using Fermat's principle, and thereby see the same result.